# Unity C# Maze Algorithm Assistance for Multiple Different Pipe Segments

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, maze

I'm trying to make a video game in Unity using C# that involves basically moving through randomly laid out pipes in a 2D grid of a fixed size.

I've poured hours of work into the texture details and such and am quite happy but wasn't expecting the algorithm bit to be so hard to do. Eventually I ended up just shelving the project to try and finish later. After about a year though I'm really ready to unshelf it and finish it.

Here's my problem of what I'm trying to achieve

There are different pipe segments:

- 4 way pipe
- straight pipe
- elbow pipe
- dead-end pipe

I need them to fill a grid of a fixed size such as a 3x3 grid or something and growing by the level. The grid, for simplicity sake, will be 2D. They obviously need to be rotated and such.

Each segment had doors that open and shut, the segments facing each other need to have one door removed so not to have duplicate doors and the doors facing the void need to never open. Some segments such as long hallways need to have their doors removed so not to have too many doors or at least on the same timer so they all open and close at same time.

Additionally certain end segments need to be spawned with fire inside while others don't. The player also need to spawn inside a random 
 end segment.

So thats all pretty complicated and I've tried at least 5 versions of algorithms but they all have failed. I'm almost to the point of making preset levels but its certainly not the route I want to go in as its the least flexible route and will just expand the game and make replaying it not very fun.

I'm also really new to algorithms like this and never done this kind of thing before.

Any help on this at all even in the right direction, idea, or whatever will be helpful, thanks.

Here's some images of what it looks like from Players POV for reference in case it helps

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Xzg.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGtag.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mi0y.jpg

EDIT:

1. My first attempt was to simply randomly place segments in every grid cell through the map at random angles. But this obviously didn't work because you just had an incoherent mess everywhere.
2. My 2nd attempt was to do that but trace from start to finish and delete the rest but that didn't work but it just cleaned up the incoherent mess and didn't work.
3. My 3rd attempt was to pick a random starting location, insert starting segment, and then just keep randomly inserting segments at random places. But this didn't work because I had multiple openings on many and the whole thing was complicated not to mention the eblow pipe kind of complicated everything and I'd have to figure out which direction to build in etc...
4. My 4th attempt was to do the 3rd attempt and then recheck every grid cell for a compatible segment that might match what's around it. Basically just keep doing a full check on all grid cells until nothing more can be done. This kind of worked but was also had flaws in it since things were generated kind of wierd or in wrong places and theres still detail that didn't work.

I think I just kept trying to fix the algorithm for try 4 before just shelving the entire project.

Comment: what have you tried so far exactly? what is the problem exactly? your description is very general and is basically asking how to program a procedural map generator. which, i'm sure you can find a few tutorials for on youtube.

Comment: @mad.meesh Thanks I added that in the edit, so its a procedural map generator tutorial I need to look into. I didn't know the name of it what I needed to look into but to answer your other question my attempts have been aded in at the end of my post.

Comment: well your 4th description is the way to go. basically you keep track of what connections a cell can make and then check its neighbors (ie, for a 2d grid with no diagonal movement you need concern yourself only with `(x-1, y)` `(x, y+1)` `(x+1, y)` `(x, y-1)`) and make adjustments as you generate.